# .NET MAUI - controller Handle address

Tags: c#, winui-3, maui

I've started playing with the latest RC release of .NET MAUI. I wish to migrate a Windows application I have, so later on it could be multi-platform. For Windows, my application needs to get the handle for a controller (then passed to a 3rd party library that makes use of it).

In my WinForms application what I usually do is something like `IntPtr controlHandle = MyControl.Handle;`

Is it possible to get the Handle on a control in .NET MAUI? I remember in the past checking this for a WPF application and for all controls it returned the main window handle address, but there was a way to create a new control with it's own handle. Is there such possibility in MAUI?

Comment: It's likely that third party application which operates on that handle is not cross platform anyway.

Comment: I'm sure it isn't. But I'm guessing there must be a way in MAUI to conditionally run code depending on the OS it's running on. So on Windows it would use that library and for MacOS it would use something else...

Comment: The closest thing I know to get platform specific things are handers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize

Answer (score 2):

just in case someone is still trying to figure this out.

```
        // Get the current window's HWND by passing in the Window object
        var hwnd = ((MauiWinUIWindow)App.Current.Windows[0].Handler.NativeView).WindowHandle;
```

references:
https://blog.verslu.is/maui/folder-picker-with-dotnet-maui/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190412-00/?p=102413